# Stuck on proof of Thm 8.4 in Baby Rudin.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Theorem 8.3: Given a double sequence $\{a_{ij}\}$ ,$i=1,2,3,\cdots$,$j=1,2,3,\cdots$, suppose that 
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty|a_{ij}|=b_i\ \ \ (i=1,2,3,\cdots)$$
and $\sum b_i$ converges. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}.$$

Theorem 8.4: Suppose 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$$
the series converging in $|x|<R$. If $-R<a<R$, then f can be expanded in a power series about the point $x=a$ which converges in $|x-a|<R-|a|$, and 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n\ \ \ (|x-a|<R-|a|)$$

Proof we have
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n[(x-a)+a]^n$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\sum_{m=0}^n\Big{(}^n_m\Big{)}a^{n-m}(x-a)^m$$
$$=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\Big{[}\sum_{n=m}^\infty\Big{(}_m^n\Big{)}c_na^{n-m}\Big{]}(x-a)^m$$

This is the desired expansion about the point $x=a$. to prove its validity, we have to justify the change which was made in order of summation. Theorem 8.3 show that this is permissible if 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\Big{|}c_n\Big{(}_m^n\Big{)}a^{n-m}(x-a)^m\Big{|}$$
converge.

Why does theorem 8.3 shows that this is permissible if 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\Big{|}c_n\Big{(}_m^n\Big{)}a^{n-m}(x-a)^m\Big{|}$$
converge?

Comment: I don't have the book: can you post the whole exercise and the theorem in question? (Maybe about changing order of summing)

Comment: We want to derive thm 8.4 using thm 8.3

Comment: I'm not squinting or stretching the image for that. Edit your post to write it in MathJax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/171839

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\sum_{m=0}^n {n\choose m}a^{n-m}(x-a)^m = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n{n\choose m}c_na^{n-m}(x-a)^m$$

and since:

$$\sum_{m=0}^n\Bigg|{n\choose m}c_na^{n-m}(x-a)^m\Bigg|<\infty$$

because it is a finite sum, you can apply Theorem 8.3 by considering the remaining terms of the sum to be zero. Thus you can permute the sums (being careful with the indexing).

Comment: Is this method reasonable? Let $s(n-m):=\Big{\{}_{0\ \ \ n<m}^{1\ \ \ n \geq m}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\sum_{m=0}^n\Big{(}^n_m\Big{)}a^{n-m}(x-a)^m$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty c_ns(n-m)\Big{(}^n_m\Big{)}a^{n-m}(x-a)^m$

Comment: and use theorem 8.3

Comment: You have to be careful because if $n<m$ the combination (or binomial coefficient) ${n\choose m}$ is not well defined. If you want to take this approach, try defining $a_{n,m} = c_na^{n-m}(x-a)^m$ for $n\geq m$ and $a_{n,m} = 0$ for $n<m$.

Comment: I apologize, I missed a combination when defining $a_{n,m}$.